# Multithreading, shared queue as synchronization point

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, asynchronous, synchronization

I have two threads, one produces images and one processes them. For the synchronization, I created a class where you can set and get images, and it always waits until an image is available or a worker thread is not busy anymore.

Additionally, a call to `SetFinish` stops both threads, while a call to `Clear` clears the currently (not yet processed) image.

Do you see any problems with this code (mainly threading issues)?

Header:

```
#ifndef SHARED_QUEUE_H_
#define SHARED_QUEUE_H_

#include <memory>
#include <condition_variable>

struct ImageData;

class SharedQueue {
public:
  void SetFinish();
  bool GetImage(std::shared_ptr<const ImageData> &image);
  void SetImage(std::shared_ptr<const ImageData> image);
  void Clear();

private:
  std::condition_variable image_available_;
  std::condition_variable image_processed_;
  std::shared_ptr<const ImageData> next_image_;
  bool stop_{false};
  std::mutex mutex_;
};

#endif  // SHARED_QUEUE_H_
```

Implementation:

```
#include "shared_queue.h"

void SharedQueue::SetFinish() {
  { // Store flag and wake up the thread
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    stop_ = true;
  }
  image_available_.notify_one();
  image_processed_.notify_one();
}

bool SharedQueue::GetImage(std::shared_ptr<const ImageData> &image) {
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    image_available_.wait(lock, [this]{
      return (next_image_.get() != nullptr || stop_);
    });

    if (stop_)
      return false;

    image = next_image_;
    next_image_.reset();
  }
  image_processed_.notify_one();
  return true;
}

void SharedQueue::SetImage(std::shared_ptr<const ImageData> image) {
  { // Store image for processing and wake up the thread
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    image_processed_.wait(lock, [this]{
      return (next_image_.get() == nullptr || stop_);
    });

    if (stop_)
      return;

    next_image_ = image;
  }
  image_available_.notify_one();
}

void SharedQueue::Clear() {
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    next_image_.reset();
  }
  image_processed_.notify_one();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not a Queue!**

First and foremost, your `SharedQueue` isn't a queue. You can only store one element in it at a time. That doesn't make it super useful - what if the producer wants to write two images?

```
queue.setImage(img1);
queue.setImage(img2); // blocks?
```

It's more of a guarantee-one-at-a-time container. A queue would be much more useful, so I'd consider actually implementing one. This is a pretty major design flaw.

---

Beyond that, I just have minor comments.

**Move semantics**

You have a lot of copies where you can do moves. For instance, in `SetImage()`:

```
next_image_ = image;
```

should be:

```
next_image_ = std::move(image);
```

Moving is cheaper than copying (no need to incur reference counting).

**Checking `shared_ptr`**

You don't need to use `.get()`, you can directly check the shared_ptr:

```
image_processed_.wait(lock, [this]{
   return !next_image_ || stop_;
});
```

**`Clear()`**

You use a `std::unique_lock<>` to `Clear()` where a `std::lock_guard<>` is sufficient. You use the correct one in `SetFinish()`.

Comment: Trivia: Java's `SynchronousQueue<E>` is even more extreme: " A synchronous queue does not have any internal capacity, _not even a capacity of one_."

Comment: @Mat That is a weird "container". I guess if OP was trying to produce that one, my main comment is moot.

Comment: @Barry thanks a lot for your helpful comments! Yes I actually had a real queue in the beginning, but I changed it. The reason is that the producer is much faster than the worker getting the images, so if I have a queue, I get more and more latency and in the end the application runs out of memory. This way, I make sure that the producer and the consumer are in "sync", processing images at the same speed, and can at the same time still exploit the speedup of multithreading.